# What is Doomsday and where did he come from?

Tags: dc, superman, doomsday

The infamous Doomsday Vs. Superman battle in the Death of Superman saga from DC is among the most famous of all comic books. I personally own most of the saga and always counted it among the legends. However, if there was a backstory to the villain I don't own it.

Where did Doomsday come from? What is he?

I'm looking for canon answers, from the ORIGINAL comics from the 90's. None of the new(er) animated movie stuff.

Comment: Did you even attempt any [research](http://superman.wikia.com/wiki/Doomsday) before posting this question?

Comment: we all have our moments when we blurt out a question as it enters our minds, rather than looking around first. Calm yourself.

Comment: @Daft - the OP is looking for canon answers from comics. Wikia has a tendency to mix canon, with unreferenced canon, with made-up stuff by Wikia writers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My answer pertains only to the modern age Doomsday.  I haven't looked into his origins in the New 52 yet:

Doomsday is a bioengineered Kryptonian creature.  This is pulled from the superman wiki... I've read the referenced comics before (Superman/Doomsday Hunter/Prey and The Death of Superman) and can confirm the info is correct: You can find Doomsday's bio [here](http://superman.wikia.com/wiki/Doomsday%27s_Biography_(Modern_Age))

> Thousands of years into Krypton's obscure past, long before the
>   humanoid Kryptonian race managed to gain dominance over the planet,
>   Doomsday was originally an infant humanoid, probably a Kryptonian; he
>   was known at this point simply as baby. An alien scientist known as
>   Bertron saw the environment of his home world. During this time,
>   Krypton was a violent and harsh world equivalent of hell, where only
>   the absolute strongest lifeforms could afford to survive. Because of
>   this, Bertron was influenced to create the perfect creature that could
>   be suitable for the Kryptonian environment and decided to perform
>   experiments on a baby. Due to the cruel nature of the experiments, the
>   baby evolved into a killing monster, with a hatred of all life.
>   (Superman/Doomsday: Hunter/Prey)
>
> Doomsday was able to escape from Krypton on a random supply ship,
>   which came regularly to bring supplies to Bertron and his team. From
>   there, he began to rampage across the universe. (Superman/Doomsday:
>   Hunter/Prey)
>
> The final planet Doomsday invaded during this era was a highly
>   advanced planet known as Catalan. All of their advanced technology was
>   unable to stop him, until they created a superbeing made of pure
>   energy, who they called The Radiant. This being was able to kill the
>   seemingly unstoppable monster, and they wrapped him up in funerary
>   clothes and tied him up as best they could, launching him into space.
>   (Superman/Doomsday: Hunter/Prey)
>
> Drifting through endless space, the coffin came to land on Earth,
>   where it remained buried for years, dormant.  He spent thousands of years buried, 
>   wiggling his way out little by little until finally escaping and
>   restarting his rampage (The Death of Superman)

Add On:

Hunter/Prey is where you'll get almost all of Doomsday's backstory.  They also did a Doomsday: Year One that builds on it a little more but I haven't read it yet

Comment: The Catalanians should've followed the #1 rule for dealing with supervillains: When in doubt, throw them into the sun.

Comment: To be more specific, Bertron was attempting to create the ultimate weapon. To do this, he allowed the baby to be killed continuously by the crystal-like creatures of Krypton, each time cloning a new baby from the remains of the dead one. Eventually, through engineering they ended up with a version that couldn't be killed the same way twice. This version grew up into Doomsday, who slaughtered the scientists and escaped on a supply ship.

Comment: @Liesmith, you dont kill Doomsday.  Anyone saying otherwise doesn't get it.  3 Supermans can't kill doomsday, what makes you think a pathetic yellow dwarf can do better?

Comment: @Virusboy It doesn't need to kill him...but he'll be stuck there forever.  There's no surface to jump off of, and nothing to punch, so Doomsday would be neutralized.

Comment: Better make sure it's a red sun and not yellow before you go throwing any Kryptonians into it.

Answer (score 9):

Doomsday's backstory is revealed mostly in a follow-up to the original *Death of Superman* storyline, in a special 3-part series called *Superman/Doomsday: Hunter/Prey". Specifically, issue 2 of that series reveals who Doomsday is and where he came from.

To summarize: he was a creature originally called "The Ultimate" that was the result of an "experiment in evolution" on prehistoric Krypton (long before the Kryptonians came there). An alien scientist sent a humanoid infant out on to Krypton (I don't think we find out where the scientist nor the infant originally came from), where he promptly died. The scientist then used his remains as the basis for a stronger version, and repeated that process until the child could survive on his own. Part of that process meant that the suffering and death of his predecessors was embedded into his DNA, producing the uncontrollable rage he suffered from.

Eventually, "The Ultimate" kills his creator and escapes from Krypton, flies around the galaxy being a murderous jerk, until he crash-lands on Earth and is buried deep underground for a long time. When he re-emerges, someone gives him the nickname Doomsday, and that leads into *Death of Superman*.

Comment: murderous jerks are the worst kind of jerks imo